# Web Host has strange settings, need alternative session state suggestions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state, sql-session-state

I am building a web site for a sports club. The club is not interested in moving their hosting to a different web host, so I'm stuck with the current host. I deployed the new web application to the host, but after a few hours of testing it became obvious something was acting weird with regards to logins and the session state.

Whenever I spent more than 10 minutes idle, all of a sudden my MVC Verification Tokens would stop decrypting. I went into IIS and set the machine key to a static value, and this problem went away, but it became obvious that they had the ASP.NET idle timeout setting set to 10 minutes. Which means that every 10 minutes InProc session data would be destroyed if there was no activity on the site. I filed a support ticket with the host, but they are unwilling to change that setting for me on my app pool, stating "The setting can't be changed on the server at this time as increasing this could affect the performance off(sic) the server".

The club is somewhat small, at most 500 members of the club and very few of the members will be accessing the site often, so I can pretty much guarantee that the 10 minute timeout will be happening multiple times a day, and I have session timeouts set to 60 minutes, so it won't be a good idea to have the site clear sessions if the sole user of the site at a given time is idle for 10 minutes.

My first thought was to use SQL session storage. I've never used it, but I know it exists. However, one caveat that exists is that we are limited to 350mb of SQL storage. While this is probably more than the site will need right now, I imagine down the line we might come close to hitting the limit. I don't anticipate storing much data in the session, only a few things when interacting with paypal and shopping carts (maybe a system message here or there as well), so perhaps this isn't a huge concern?

We *do* have unlimited disk space, so another alternative I thought about was to perhaps write a custom disk-based session storage solution. Is there any reason this might not be a better idea than SQL?

And finally, I had a totally off-the-wall "oh god I can't believe I'm thinking about doing this" idea, which would be to have an AJAX call on every page periodically (say, every 8 minutes) "ping" a non-cached lightweight MVC action just to keep the server alive. This would probably work, I think, except for the one scenario where someone:

1. goes to the shopping page and creates a cart
2. gets transferred to paypal
3. spends 10+ minutes on the paypal screen for whatever reason while nobody else is on the site
4. comes back to see their cart disappear.

In this instance I might just move carts to the database anyway.

So... thoughts, comments, suggestions? I'm really frustrated about the host not letting me change this setting and my first instinct would be to find another host, but as I said before, the club has some strange attachment to the host and doesn't want to move somewhere else.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

**On the problem:** It's common for sessions to be 'lost' on Load Balancing systems. This could possibly be fixed by moving to a single designated server (if the hosting company isn't doing this now and provides the option

**Cookie sessions:** If you're using .Net Membership, you can change the login process to use cookies. This comes with the obvious *some users dont allow cookies* pitfall. Again, a consideration. Currently working on a school site where they want users to remain logged in.

** With Cookies your Login is stable, but your sessions will not be any better kept. So you're out of luck carrying much to count on in the Session State.

The end result is that you can track users by IP or Cookie, but unless this is a fixable Load Balancing problem, you're heading toward a Session-less application.

Comment: I've spent a few days contemplating your comments about going sessionless. I didn't want to go down that route because Session is so easy to use. But after playing around with a few alternatives I tossed out in the original question, it's become obvious that session just will never be reliable for me, and that I need to move towards a sessionless app. Luckily there's only one major thing that needs to be refactored and I can think sessionless for the rest of the app.

Comment: I understand your pain. Working on a project with 'permanent logins' meaning cookies. Result of that was Sessions could never be reliable in scope of logins. First we put effort into 'maintaining' session objects. After a while the maintenance logic was its own maintenance colossus. After all that we abandoned sessions. Good luck. It's not easy.